# Rotate PDF around its center using PDFBox in java

Tags: java, pdfbox

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(input));
PDPage page = document.getDocumentCatalog().getPages().get(0);
PDPageContentStream cs = new PDPageContentStream(document, page,PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.PREPEND, false, false); 
cs.transform(Matrix.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(45), 0, 0));
```

I am using the above code to rotate the PDF.

[image]

For the above image, i am getting following output

[image]

From that code, the content of the page has been moving out of the frame and the rotation is not happening around its center. But i want to get the output as

[image]

Please suggest me some options. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you hope the page will eventually be displayed in a tilted rectangle. It won't. PDF pages always have edges which are either vertical or horizontal. The *content* of such a page may be arbitrarily oriented. To have the rotated content inside the visible rectangle (with horizontal/vertical edges), you can shift it there using the additional two parameters of the `Matrix.getRotateInstance` call (you left them `0,0`) or you can move the visible rectangle by setting the mediabox and cropbox of the page accordingly.

Comment: The second and the third argument to `getRotateInstance` are the x and y translation done before and after rotating so that you're effectively rotating around a different point than the origin. Try half the page width as the x and half the page height as the y. If it doesn't work, put a minus sign in front of both - I always forget if you should specify it as the translation towards the origin (in which case they should be negative) or as the point to rotate around (in which case they should be positive)

Comment: @mkl - I tried with setting media and crop boxes as
page.setCropBox(new PDRectangle(0f,0f,595f,841f));
page.setMediaBox(new PDRectangle(0f,0f,595f,841f));
But getting the same result

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt - I tried with x and y tranlations by setting the values with half of their values for both cases(positive and negative) .  But still unable to get the correct result.

Comment: *"I tried with setting media and crop boxes as page.setCropBox(new PDRectangle(0f,0f,595f,841f)); page.setMediaBox(new PDRectangle(0f,0f,595f,841f)); But getting the same result"* - Obviously.You rotate the page to the left side, thus its content partially now has negative *x* coordinate values. To have it inside the boxes, the boxes must start with negative *x* coordinates, too, not 0 as you chose.

Comment: *But still unable to get the correct result.* - One problem for me is that it is entirely unclear which is the *correct result*. In particular, after rotating around the center do you want the parts of the content which rotated out of the page area to remain hidden? Or shall the page area be enlarged sufficiently to make all content show? Or shall the content be scaled down enough so that all of it fits into the original page are again?

Comment: @mkl -  *In particular, after rotating around the center* - currently the rotation has been happening by considering  bottom left as origin. It would be very helpful if its possible to do it by taking center of the page as origin. After rotation, i want to hidden the area which is out of page.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are two major ways to rotate the page content and make it appear in a viewer as if the rotation happened around the middle of the visible page: Either one actually does rotate around the middle of it by concatenating the rotation with translations or one moves the crop box so that the page area center follow the rotation.

### Actually rotating around the center

To do this we envelop the rotation between two translations, the first one moves the origin of the coordinate system to the page center and the second one moves it back again.

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(resource);
PDPage page = document.getDocumentCatalog().getPages().get(0);
PDPageContentStream cs = new PDPageContentStream(document, page, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.PREPEND, false, false); 
PDRectangle cropBox = page.getCropBox();
float tx = (cropBox.getLowerLeftX() + cropBox.getUpperRightX()) / 2;
float ty = (cropBox.getLowerLeftY() + cropBox.getUpperRightY()) / 2;
cs.transform(Matrix.getTranslateInstance(tx, ty));
cs.transform(Matrix.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(45), 0, 0));
cs.transform(Matrix.getTranslateInstance(-tx, -ty));
cs.close();
```

*([RotatePageContent](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/content/RotatePageContent.java#L61) test `testRotateCenter`)*

Obviously you can multiply the matrices and only add a single transformation to the PDF.

### Pulling the crop box along

To do this we calculate the move of the page center and move the boxes accordingly.

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(resource);
PDPage page = document.getDocumentCatalog().getPages().get(0);
PDPageContentStream cs = new PDPageContentStream(document, page, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.PREPEND, false, false);
Matrix matrix = Matrix.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(45), 0, 0);
cs.transform(matrix);
cs.close();

PDRectangle cropBox = page.getCropBox();
float cx = (cropBox.getLowerLeftX() + cropBox.getUpperRightX()) / 2;
float cy = (cropBox.getLowerLeftY() + cropBox.getUpperRightY()) / 2;
Point2D.Float newC = matrix.transformPoint(cx, cy);
float tx = (float)newC.getX() - cx;
float ty = (float)newC.getY() - cy;
page.setCropBox(new PDRectangle(cropBox.getLowerLeftX() + tx, cropBox.getLowerLeftY() + ty, cropBox.getWidth(), cropBox.getHeight()));
PDRectangle mediaBox = page.getMediaBox();
page.setMediaBox(new PDRectangle(mediaBox.getLowerLeftX() + tx, mediaBox.getLowerLeftY() + ty, mediaBox.getWidth(), mediaBox.getHeight()));
```

*([RotatePageContent](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/content/RotatePageContent.java#L125) test `testRotateMoveBox`)*

### Scaling the content down to fit after rotation

If one wants to scale down the rotated content to make it all fit, one can do this as an easy extension of the first variant:

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(resource);
PDPage page = document.getDocumentCatalog().getPages().get(0);
PDPageContentStream cs = new PDPageContentStream(document, page, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.PREPEND, false, false);

Matrix matrix = Matrix.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(45), 0, 0);
PDRectangle cropBox = page.getCropBox();
float tx = (cropBox.getLowerLeftX() + cropBox.getUpperRightX()) / 2;
float ty = (cropBox.getLowerLeftY() + cropBox.getUpperRightY()) / 2;

Rectangle rectangle = cropBox.transform(matrix).getBounds();
float scale = Math.min(cropBox.getWidth() / (float)rectangle.getWidth(), cropBox.getHeight() / (float)rectangle.getHeight());

cs.transform(Matrix.getTranslateInstance(tx, ty));
cs.transform(matrix);
cs.transform(Matrix.getScaleInstance(scale, scale));
cs.transform(Matrix.getTranslateInstance(-tx, -ty));
cs.close();
```

*([RotatePageContent](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/content/RotatePageContent.java#L89) test `testRotateCenterScale`)*

### Changing the crop box to make all former page area remain visible

If one wants instead to change the crop box to make everything fit without scaling, one can do this as an easy extension of the second variant:

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(resource);
PDPage page = document.getDocumentCatalog().getPages().get(0);
PDPageContentStream cs = new PDPageContentStream(document, page, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.PREPEND, false, false);
Matrix matrix = Matrix.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(45), 0, 0);
cs.transform(matrix);
cs.close();

PDRectangle cropBox = page.getCropBox();
Rectangle rectangle = cropBox.transform(matrix).getBounds();
PDRectangle newBox = new PDRectangle((float)rectangle.getX(), (float)rectangle.getY(), (float)rectangle.getWidth(), (float)rectangle.getHeight());
page.setCropBox(newBox);
page.setMediaBox(newBox);
```

*([RotatePageContent](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/content/RotatePageContent.java#L160) test `testRotateExpandBox`)*

### Sample results

The following image shows an output for each of the methods above:

[image: Screenshot]

1. Actually rotating around the center
2. Scaling the content down to fit after rotation
3. Pulling the crop box along
4. Changing the crop box to make all former page area remain visible

Image 4 is not at the same scale as the others, it should show larger.

Comment: Thanks mkl. I got perfect results. Thank you once again for such a detailed explanation.

Comment: The `document.save()` command is in the RotatePageContent test example but isn't in the actual answer.

Comment: Indeed, the code here focuses on instantiating required objects and using them to create the desired effect. Whether afterwards the documents are saved somewhere or otherwise used, e.g. copied page-wise into other documents, is not of interest here.

Comment: @mkl I appreciate your detailed answer. My comment was just to help someone who knows nothing about pdfBox (like me) save some time. Not to criticize your answer.

Comment: What's the purpose of Matrix.getTranslateInstance(tx, ty) and Matrix.getTranslateInstance(-tx, -ty)?

Comment: @nishantbhardwaj2002 The matrix rotation always work around point [0,0], to rotate the image around it's center, you have to first move the image so it's center is at [0,0] and then translate it back where it was.

Comment: How about doc.getDocumentCatalog().getPages().get(0).setRotation(sth);

Comment: @TugalsanKarabacak *"How about doc.getDocumentCatalog().getPages().get(0).setRotation(sth)"* - the page rotation property only allows rotation by multiples of 90°.