# how to get new coordinate after affine transformation using pdfbox in java

Tags: java, pdfbox

I have following pdf with crop box as shown below
[image]

Rotated the page to make it horizontal using below code

```
PDPageContentStream cs = new PDPageContentStream(document, page, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.PREPEND, false, false); 
PDRectangle cropBox = page.getCropBox();
float tx = (cropBox.getLowerLeftX() + cropBox.getUpperRightX()) / 2;
float ty = (cropBox.getLowerLeftY() + cropBox.getUpperRightY()) / 2;
cs.transform(Matrix.getTranslateInstance(tx, ty));
cs.transform(Matrix.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(5), 0, 0));
cs.transform(Matrix.getTranslateInstance(-tx, -ty));
cs.close();
```

The result from above code is
[image]

Since coordinates has been changed after affine transformation, for old crop box coordinates i am getting different section. I want to get the original section which i had pointed before rotation.

So,I have tried following  techniques to get new coordinates, but didn't get the result

```
 double x_transformed = (x*Math.cos(angle))-(y*Math.sin(angle));
 double y_transformed = (x*Math.sin(angle))+(y*Math.cos(angle));
 double X_transformed = (X*Math.cos(angle))-(Y*Math.sin(angle));
 double Y_transformed = (X*Math.sin(angle))+(Y*Math.cos(angle));
```

Please suggest me solutions from which i can exactly crop the required section.
[image]

The data provided in the question is for reference only.Actual input files can get from below link :

drive.google.com/open?id=0BxPYWA8sfqTDVmY5YVQyZTZwSTA

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share the pdf. The coordinates you present for the crop box look odd.

Comment: @mkl sorry.It is my mistake. Actually i have given sample values not exact one. I will share proper inputs and let you know.

Comment: @mkl - i have kept sample files on below link
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxPYWA8sfqTDVmY5YVQyZTZwSTA 
Please do needful help

Comment: It took me some time to get back to your question. The cause actually is simple, you either have to rotate not around the center of the original crop box but around the center of your section box, or you have to first crop down to the section and then rotate, or you have to change the coordinates you crop down to by the vector the sector center has been moved by the rotation. Cf. my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you rotated the page around the center of the *original* crop box of the page (which defaults to the media box):

```
PDRectangle cropBox = page.getCropBox();
float tx = (cropBox.getLowerLeftX() + cropBox.getUpperRightX()) / 2;
float ty = (cropBox.getLowerLeftY() + cropBox.getUpperRightY()) / 2;
```

and thereafter you restrict to your new crop box:

```
int x = 39;
int y = 450;
int x2 = 360;
int y2= 500;
page.setCropBox(new PDRectangle(new BoundingBox((int)x, (int)y,(int)x2, (int)y2)));
```

---

In your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40611736/1729265) your task was to keep the center of the page crop box fixed and rotate everything around it. Thus, there it was correct to calculate the `tx` and `ty` from the page crop box.

Your task now, on the other hand, is to keep the center of the box fixed to which you eventually want to crop the page.

---

Thus, you now have to calculate `tx` and `ty` using the corners of that other box:

```
float tx = (x + x2) / 2;
float ty = (y + y2) / 2;
```

Alternatively you can simply change the order and first crop the page to the box between (x,y) and (x2,y2) and then rotate around the center of the changed crop box.

Yet another option would be to change the new crop box coordinates by the vector its center has been moved by the rotation.