# Rotate pdf content without rotating Page or PDF using PDF box

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am using PDFBOX 1.8. Currently if the PDF is in Landscape mode then rotating it to Portrait mode with following

```
public static byte[] rotatePDF(byte[] inputPdf) throws Exception {

    PDDocument  document = PDDocument.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(inputPdf));
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputByte = new ByteArrayOutputStream();     
    List<PDPage> pages = (List) document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
    int rotation=0;     
    for (int i = 0; i < pages.size(); i++) {

        PDPage page = pages.get(i);         
        rotation=page.findRotation();
            page.setRotation(rotation+90);           
    }

    try {
        document.save(outputByte);
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    document.close();

    return outputByte.toByteArray(); 
}
```

But if the PDF is in Portrait mode but its content is in Landscape mode. How to rotate only the content?

ex. Here I want only HELLO WORLD should be rotated.

[image: Example I want rotate only HELLO WORLD as PDF is already in Portrait mode]

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40630514/1729265) help?

Comment: @mkl Which version of Pdfbox is used? I am getting error for some of methods like - The method getRotateInstance(double, int, int) is undefined for the type Matrix

Comment: That referenced answer is for PDFBox 2. (If it was for PDFBox 1.8.x, I'd have marked your question as duplicate.) If the code in principle does what you need, it should not be too difficult to backport.

Comment: @mkl I tried migrating to PDFBox 2, but it requires major code changes in my project. Any help with with 1.8 would be greatful.

Comment: I'll have a look later. This week, though, I'm on vacation... ;)