# How to adjust the angle of text or image?

Tags: java, pdfbox

When I used PDPageContentStream.transform to adjust the angle of the text or image to generate a watermark, I found that the position of the watermark would be shifted.

Is there any good way to solve this problem?

Can I rotate based on the angle or is there a tool to generate Matrix objects based on the angle?

```
public static void addTextWatermark(PDDocument doc, PDPage page, PDFont font, TextParam param)
            throws IOException {
        try (PDPageContentStream cs
                     = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, true, true)) {

            //There is a problem
            cs.transform(Matrix.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(param.getDegree()), 0, 0));
            
            cs.setFont(font, param.getFontSize());
            PDExtendedGraphicsState gs = new PDExtendedGraphicsState();
            gs.setNonStrokingAlphaConstant(param.getDissolve() / 100f);
            gs.setStrokingAlphaConstant(param.getDissolve() / 100f);

            gs.setBlendMode(BlendMode.MULTIPLY);
            gs.setLineWidth(3f);
            cs.setGraphicsStateParameters(gs);

            //设置字体和边框颜色
            cs.setNonStrokingColor(new Color(param.getFills()[0], param.getFills()[1], param.getFills()[2]));
            cs.setStrokingColor(new Color(param.getFills()[0], param.getFills()[1], param.getFills()[2]));

            cs.beginText();
            cs.newLineAtOffset(0, 0);
            cs.showText(param.getText());
            cs.endText();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The rotation is around (0,0) which is the bottom left. The `AddWatermarkText.java` example shows how to do a watermark. If that isn't the question, maybe the answer is you need to use `saveGraphicsState()` and `restoreGraphicsState()`.

Answer (score 3):

As @Tilman already mentioned, transforming by `Matrix.getRotateInstance(angle, x, y)` rotates around the origin (0, 0) of the coordinate system (which usually is the lower left corner of a page) and then translates by (x, y).

You on the other hand likely want to rotate around a different point, probably around the center of the page (or the center of your watermark). You can rotate around an arbitrary point by enveloping the rotation between two translations that first move that desired center to the origin and afterwards back to its original position, i.e. for a rotation center at (tx, ty) do

```java
cs.transform(Matrix.getTranslateInstance(tx, ty));
cs.transform(Matrix.getRotateInstance(angle, 0, 0));
cs.transform(Matrix.getTranslateInstance(-tx, -ty));
```

---

By the way, this technique has been used in the first option of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40630514/1729265) on the topic of *rotating a PDF around its center*.